# How to install Magento 2 with empty database password

Tags: magento2, install

I'm trying to install Magento 2 on server which doesn't use database password. It's a kind of cloud hosting and I don't have ability to set password there.

Is there any way to install M2 using CLI with empty password?

I tried this installation command call:

```
cd bin/; /usr/bin/php ./magento setup:install \
        --currency=USD \
        --base-url=<URL> \
        --base-url-secure=<URL> \
        --language=en_US \
        --timezone=America/Los_Angeles \
        --db-host=<HOST> \
        --db-name=main \
        --db-user=user \
        --backend-frontname=admin \
        --admin-user=admin \
        --admin-firstname=John \
        --admin-lastname=Doe \
        --admin-email=john@example.com \
        --admin-password=admin12
```

And I got exception:

```
Configuration array must have a key for 'password' for login credentials
```

Then I tried to provide empty password:

```
cd bin/; /usr/bin/php ./magento setup:install \
        --currency=USD \
        --base-url=<URL> \
        --base-url-secure=<URL> \
        --language=en_US \
        --timezone=America/Los_Angeles \
        --db-host=<HOST> \
        --db-name=main \
        --db-user=user \
        --db-password='' \
        --backend-frontname=admin \
        --admin-user=admin \
        --admin-firstname=John \
        --admin-lastname=Doe \
        --admin-email=john@example.com \
        --admin-password=admin12
```

But got another exception:

```
The "--db-password" option requires a value.
```

Do you know if Magento 2 installation on database server which doesn't use password is supported?

It worked fine for me with Magento 1, I've just provided empty password there:

```
--db_pass '' \
```

Comment: Are you really, really sure you want to do that anyway?

Comment: Ha, unfortunately yes.

Comment: It worked for me: --admin-password '' without '='

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following works for me on Ubuntu:

```
./bin/magento setup:install \
    --db-host=localhost \
    --db-name=magento \
    --db-user=root \
    --backend-frontname=admin \
    --base-url=http://some.host/ \
    --language=en_US \
    --timezone=America/Chicago \
    --currency=USD \
    --admin-lastname=Admin \
    --admin-firstname=Admin \
    --admin-email=admin@example.com \
    --admin-user=admin \
    --admin-password=123123q \
    --cleanup-database \
    --use-rewrites=1
```

The problem may be that you are using remote MySQL host, not `localhost`. Not sure that it is possible to connect to remote MySQL host without password.

Comment: I tried to add `--cleanup-database` option and ran `setup:uninstall` and it went through. I'm not sure what happened, it may be that credentials set in wrong way were cached or stored in config.php file. Thanks for help.

Comment: remove `"--db-password" option` from command.

Answer (score 0):

Remove --db-password and use an alpha-numeric password of at least 7 chars for --admin-password

```
cd bin/; /usr/bin/php ./magento setup:install \
    --currency=USD \
    --base-url=<URL> \
    --base-url-secure=<URL> \
    --language=en_US \
    --timezone=America/Los_Angeles \
    --db-host=<HOST> \
    --db-name=main \
    --db-user=user \
    --backend-frontname=admin \
    --admin-user=admin \
    --admin-firstname=John \
    --admin-lastname=Doe \
    --admin-email=john@example.com \
    --admin-password=admin12
```

Comment: I'm sorry for confusion, I already used admin password according to requirements, I just modified my code sample to avoid showing real password there. I modified it again to show it uses proper password. However, without `--db-password ` option I'm getting exception which looks as coming from `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract`.

Comment: too bad, it would have been easy :) what is the version of /usr/bin/php? and could you check that php.ini used by /usr/bin/php is correctly configured? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html

Comment: PHP looked good, it looks something got cached on previous invalid command call. Thanks!